# How to check if object key exists and is not null or if it is a certain value in a foreach loop in Laravel blade?

Tags: php, foreach, laravel-blade, key-value

I have a **foreach** loop in **blade** where I am looping through an **array of items**, and some items has an additional key called **validation_status** which is either **null** or an **object.**

An example:

```
category: "Storage"
client_id: 6575
created_at: "2019-08-12 15:50:04"
created_by: 233
datasheet: null
deleted_at: null
description: "3erty"
energy_rating: 0
fk_item_type: 83
id: 369
item_model_id: 475
model_number: null
power_consumption: 3
searchable: 1
shared: 1
updated_at: "2019-11-09 17:59:04"
updated_by: 233
validated: 0
validation_status: null
vendor: null

category: "Network"
client_id: 6575
created_at: "2019-07-11 16:04:56"
created_by: 233
datasheet: null
deleted_at: null
description: "2we5"
energy_rating: 0
fk_item_type: 83
id: 357
item_model_id: 470
model_number: null
power_consumption: 55
searchable: 1
shared: 1
updated_at: "2019-11-07 10:29:57"
updated_by: 233
validated: 0
validation_status:
created_at: "2019-11-07 16:08:49"
id: 2
item_id: 357
item_type: "IT_Analysis"
message: null
name: "pending"
updated_at: "2019-11-07 16:08:49"
__proto__: Object
vendor: null
```

I want to do something if **validation_status** in first place **exists** and if its **key** called **name** is a **certain value** for example "pending". How can I do that in blade?

Here is my try, where right now the **else condition** gets executed as **true**, so something is wrong with my **if condition**:

```
    <p>
    @if($item->validation_status && $item->validation_status !== null) 
    @if($item->validation_status->name  === "pending" )
     <?php echo link_to('admin/items/' . $item->id . '/validation-status' . $item->validation_status->id . '/complete', 'Validate', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary w-full')); ?>
     <?php echo link_to('admin/items/' . $item->id . '/validation-status' . $item->validation_status->id . '/documentation-needed', 'Request documentation', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary w-full')); ?>
     <?php echo link_to('admin/items/' . $item->id . '/validation-status' . $item->validation_status->id . '/reject', 'Reject', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary w-full')); ?>
    @endif
    @else
      <?php echo Form::submit('Accept and Save!', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary w-full')); ?>
    @endif
    </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's an object, not an array.

```php
@php $check = isset($items->validation_status); @endphp
```

isset() will return false if the property doesn't exist or if it is null.

So it's perfect for your situation.

```php
@if($check)
    //Execute your code
@endif
```

Comment: I tried but it does not work, it`s still the **else statement** that gets executed...

Comment: Then there is only one logical cause, for whatever reason your value is not getting set. Can you show how are you assigning that property? Attach the controller code maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Way more clear way is to use Laravel build-in helper 'optional'

For example, this code will not throw an error if the relation is null

```
  {{ optional($this->category)->name }}
```